# Can Xen be configured to dedicate only one port of a dual-port NIC to a domU?

Tags: linux, virtualization, centos, xen

I'm using CentOS 5.4 on my dom0 with a stock Xen kernel.  I'm attempting to use the pciback module to hide some of the Ethernet ports from the host and reserve them for a domU I intend to use for a firewall ([process described here](http://yoonkit.blogspot.com/2009/02/xen-domu-having-exclusive-use-of.html) and [here](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/linux-lotus-domino/centos-5-and-pciback-aka-hiding-pci-card-from-xen-dom0/)).  However, when I launch the domU, I get the following error message:

```
Using config file "/etc/xen/firewall".
Error: pci: improper device assignment specified: pci: 0000:01:04.0 must be co-assigned to the same guest with 0000:01:06.0, but it is not owned by pciback.
```

lspci gives me the following output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ/P/PL Memory Controller Hub (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR/GH (ICH7 Family) SATA IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 01)
01:04.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
01:06.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
01:07.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
```

From the sound of the error message, it seems like I also need to dedicate eth0 (PCI ID 01:04.0) to the domU.  Am I correct?  If not, what am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct - multifunction devices (by [spec](http://lists.xensource.com/archives/html/xen-devel/2010-01/msg00870.html)) must be assigned to the same domain.

However, in certain cases it will still work. You may get lucky - looks you have multiple devices on the same card rather than a single multifunction device.

Try setting `pci-passthrough-strict-check no` in `/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp` and it just may work.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately.  :-\  Thanks, but do you have any other suggestions?

If I stick a PCI WiFi card in the system, I get a similar error that indicates that I need to assign the wifi card too the domU as well as the standard Ethernet ports.  This doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Well, removing the "#" at the beginning of the line might be a bit more helpful. ;-)  Works now.  Thanks a lot for the assistance; this has given me a headache all day!